# Какое отрицательное влияние окажет утрата DNS-записи SOA?

Tags: dns, vps

На данный момент некоторое доменное имя имеет DNS-записи SOA и SPF. На новом VPS указание SOA и SPF не поддерживается. Какое отрицательное влияние будет при утрате SOA и SPF (в особенности, конечно, SOA, потому что, как я понял, SPF в современности значимости не имеет).

Comment: SPF нужна и проверяется ведущими почтовыми сервисами. Например, откройте исходный текст письма в Gmail, и увидите результат проверок SPF, DKIM, DMARC.

Comment: @KAGG Design, А почему тогда в [статье в Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9_DNS) эта запись вычеркнута?

Comment: Об этом надо спросить у тех, кто писал статью. Я видел ту статью о SOA, в ней нет пояснения, что означает перечеркнутый текст. Почитайте более надёжные источники https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=ru

Comment: не раскрыта сама суть проблемы: а какое вообще отношение веб-хостинг имеет к вашему домену?

Comment: Может быть и никакого. Я знаю только то, что в админ-панели VPS есть функция добавления DNS и редактирования записей DNS, хотя использование стороннего DNS также возможно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корректная зона без SOA записи просто невозможна, так как тогда она не будет соответствовать RFC 1035. Другое дело что обычно этой записью заведует администратор DNS сервера, а если вы не администратор DNS сервера, то доступ к изменению этой записи вам не нужен. В ней нет ничего такого что вам *на практике* нужно было бы менять.

Отдельная запись SPF следует заменить обычной TXT записью. Тип записей SPF зачеркнут совершенно корректно, такой тип практически не используется на практике для указания обычных параметров SPF.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Подскажите, Вы под сервером имеете ввиду DNS-сервер?

Comment: Да, DNS-сервер вроде BIND